# Why is accelerating more air slower more efficient than less air faster?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aircraft, propulsion

According to [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/104407/70478) on Aviation Stack Exchange, when propelling an airplane it is more efficient to accelerate a bigger amount of air a little than to accelerate a small amount of air a lot. Why is that?

> So, because of the v^2, you obviously get more force for your energy input if you accelerate a lot of air by very little speed, instead of accelerating very little air by a lot.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? The mathematical description should already be in the linked question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of assumptions in the answer that you linked to is that the purpose of accelerating the air is to use the reaction force to lift an object off the ground. Force is change in momentum per unit time. So to generate a given force $F$ we have to accelerate a mass $m$ of air each second from rest to a speed $v$ where

$F = mv$

The energy that we use to do this is (at least) the kinetic energy added to the air, which is

$\displaystyle E = \frac 1 2 mv^2$

But we could choose to accelerate a larger mass of air (say a mass $m' = 2m$) to a slower speed (say $v' = \frac v 2$). We still have

$F = m'v'$

so we are still producing the required force. But the energy required to do this is now

$\displaystyle E' = \frac 1 2 (m')(v')^2 = \frac 1 2 (2m) \left( \frac v 2 \right)^2 = \frac 1 4 mv^2 = \frac 1 2 E$

So by accelerating a larger mass of air to a lower speed we produce the same reaction force but use only half the energy - which is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

That answer is extremely specific to a specific question and not a general statement about air.

They were particularly concerned with maximizing the force generated.  The force of a body of air is proportional to its velocity.  The energy of that air is proportional to its velocity squared.  This means that using faster air requires substantially more energy per unit force.

Note there's other effects that could matter, outside of the linked question.  A small amount of fast moving air will typically experience more air friction, tugging at whatever walls you are containing this airflow in.  Large volumes of slow moving air experience less friction.  But that's not the particular mechanic being quoted in the answer.